# Is there a way i can parse a particular field for making visualization in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

Below is my message field:

2020-03-05 13:00:03,957 | INFO  | p1105444158-1049 | RouteEventNotifier               | v1-individuals-retrieveContacts | 2 | Txid : d6946e71-deeb-4a63-9f78-65bdf3c67f7167_76df5b15-ca17-488e-a280-53d167222b70 | csr-web |  | t-mcespinfdoza@gmail.com| 6a379b43-b849-455a-8e75-715f70649fe7 | AccountDataPrivacy,CARE_MANUAL_ASSIGN,AdjustmentCreate,CaseEdit,OrderAddOn,CARE_CASE_REASSIGN,OrderNextBestAction,CCADashboardAccess,AdjustmentApproval,CARE_AUTO_ASSIGN,AccountUpdate,AccountView,uma_authorization |  | 361 - bil-core - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | >>>>Route:rt-BlCore Took 34 ms to send to: Endpoint[direct-vm://nullRoute]

here i want to make a visualization using string "34 ms" in order to calculate average time taken by any connector using Kibana dsl query.

Answer (score 0):

While indexing the data into Elasticsearch, you can apply an ingest pipeline with [Grok Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html) or [Grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.6/plugins-filters-grok.html) in Logstash to extract the required information and index it in a different field on which you can create a Kibana visualization.

I would recommend utilizing the [Grok debugging tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-grokdebugger.html) in Kibana to come up with the Grok pattern that you need to extract the required information.